# Is hybridization of the cyclopropyl anion sp5?

Tags: organic-chemistry, molecular-structure, hybridization

I have read some answers about the $\mathrm{sp^5}$ hybridisation of carbon atoms in the $\ce{C-C}$ bond in cyclopropane as well as the $\sigma$-bond resonance in methylcyclopropyl cation.

Overall, the answers say that the $\ce{H-C}$ bond is due to overlap of $\mathrm{sp^2}$ orbital of carbon and $\mathrm{1s}$ orbital of hydrogen, while the bent bonds of the ring are formed by overlap of $\mathrm{sp^5}$ hybrid orbitals.

But, overall true separation of orbitals in such cases is not defined i.e. we cannot say that some orbital is completely $\mathrm{sp^2}$ hybridised.

Similarly, if the loss of a proton occurs from cyclopropane then the following:

[image: Source: chemthes.com]

In such an ion, will the hybridization change and $\mathrm{s}$ and $\mathrm{p}$ characters of the orbitals be redistributed?

My assumptions for this are:

- In the $\mathrm{sp^2}$ bond the lone pair due to loss of proton will pose increased steric hinderance as it occupies greater volume. This will cause increased repulsion and decreases stability. Moreover, shouldn't the $\mathrm{s}$-character increase to accommodate the increased negative charge?
- Accordingly, wouldn't the $\mathrm{sp^5}$ bonds will now have greater $\mathrm{p}$-character to ease even greater strain produced?

Then, what will be the change in the hybridisation in the overall molecule on formation of this ion?

**References:**

- [Sp5 hybridization in cyclopropane?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37255/sp5-hybridization-in-cyclopropane)
- [Are the triply-bonded carbons in pyridyne (and benzyne) sp-hybridised?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/114879/are-the-triply-bonded-carbons-in-pyridyne-and-benzyne-sp-hybridised/114929#114929)
- [Non-integer hybridization](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/236/non-integer-hybridization/101282#101282)
- https://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=14548

Comment: Initially, I thought about an accidental claim of an carbon atom orbital thought to be hybridized $sp^5$ (with a five) instead of $sp^3$ (with a three), because the hybridizations of carbon atom orbitals taught in school are $sp$, $sp^2$, and $sp^3$.  Because the body of your question repeats the claim of $sp^5$ more than once, may you either indicate a reference for this unusual concept, or consider to revert (back) to $sp^3$ (because, the cyclopropyl anion still is a cyclopropane)?

Comment: @Buttonwood I have included some references.

Comment: I tried to check your claims, it seems that, C-C bond (without anion) came out to be $\ce{sp^{3.5}}$ and the anion ones are $\ce{sp^{2.6}}$ towards, $\ce{sp^{4.06}}$ away and the lone pair was in $\ce{sp^{1.64}}$. so i think there wont be sterric hinderance,due to the s, but p character decreased against your claim

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Yes, so it does not account to any whole number value in either contribution. What do we do in such a case?

Comment: I do not have a clear answer about that, because it is an aromatic molecule as well...so there should be an average $\ce{sp^r}$ . My calculated values corresponds to a static state

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi It doesn't have unsaturation. Should it be aromatic?

Comment: Any further information regarding this compund will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ADITYAROYCHOWDHURY yes, I read it in a book...I will share the name as well (can't find it right now)....I think it was written that it will do intra-molecular proton transfer to delocalize the charge

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Thank you, will wait.

Comment: Michael B. Smith- March's advanced organic chemistry_ reactions and mechanisms and structure-wiley 2020

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Thank you, will definitely give it a read.

Comment: I was reading it, I couldnt find it though....Also, I maybe $5\%$ wrong about aromatic nature...I was just going through the huckel MO, and found that there is a small break in the orbitals plotted at -16.266eV (in the negative sign of wave region) (It might be due to a computational fault)

Comment: It's reasonable to ask when you've pushed a model like hybridization farther than it can be pushed to be useful.

Comment: @Zhe So hybridization cannot be used to explain this?

Comment: I don't even know what you are saying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Background**

[Charles Coulson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Coulson) was the originator of **Coulson's Theorem**, a useful tool for the chemist.  It allows you to make "back of the envelope" estimations of hybridization if bond angles are known. Conversely, if one knows the hybridization from, say, $\mathrm{p}K_\text{a}$ or $J_{C^{13}-H}$ data, then the bond angle can be estimated.
The key equation is $$\ce{1+\lambda_{i} \lambda_{j} cos(\theta_{ij})=0}$$

where $\ce{\lambda_{i}}$ represents the hybridization index of the $\ce{C-i}$ bond (the hybridization index is the square root of the bond hybridization) and $\ce{\theta_{ij}}$ represents the $\ce{i-C-j}$ bond angle.

[image: angle described in Coulson's Theorem]

See these earlier answers for interesting examples where the theorem is applied:

- [estimating the hybidization in cyclopropane](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/10653/why-does-cyclopropane-react-with-bromine/10666#10666)
- [angle of attack of a nucleophile at a carbonyl](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39428/nucleophilic-attack-at-a-carbonyl-angle-of-attack/39432#39432)
- [the lone pairs in water are non-equivalent - the resultant hybridization of water](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41189/estimation-of-the-bond-angle-of-water/41206#41206)

**The Question**

The $\ce{H-C-H}$ angle in cyclopropane has been measured to be 114°.  From this, and using Coulson's theorem

$$1 + \lambda^2 \cos(114^\circ) = 0$$

where $\ce{\lambda^2}$ represents the hybridization index of the bond, the $\ce{C-H}$ bonds in cyclopropane can be deduced to be $\mathrm{sp^{2.46}}$ hybridized. Using the equation

$$\frac{2}{1 + \lambda_{\ce{C-H}}^2} + \frac{2}{1 + \lambda_{\ce{C-C}}^2} = 1$$

(which says that summing the "s" character in all bonds at a given carbon must total to 1), we find that $\lambda_{\ce{C-C}}^2 = 3.74$, or the C–C bond is $\mathrm{sp^{3.74}}$ hybridized.

Now, if we remove a proton from cyclopropane and generate the cyclopropyl anion, we move from a situation where we had a pair of electrons shared between carbon and hydrogen in a $\ce{C-H}$ bond to a situation (the anion) where we have a pair of electrons residing entirely in an orbital on the carbon atom.  In other words, we have increased the electron density in this carbon orbital.  [**Bent's Rule**](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15620/what-is-bents-rule/15622#15622) tells us that **the molecular geometry will change so as to lower the energy of this pair of electrons** and that it will lower the energy of these electrons by increasing the s-character of the orbital they are in.  In order to increase the s-character in this orbital, we will take some s-character away from the 2 $\ce{C-C}$ bonds and 1 remaining $\ce{C-H}$ bond.  Hence, $$\lambda^2_{\ce{C-C}}>3.74$$ $$\lambda^2_{\ce{C-H}}>2.46$$ and $$\lambda^2_{\ce{C-electron pair}}<2.46$$
Said differently, the interorbital (not internuclear) $\ce{C-C-C}$ angle at the anionic carbon will decrease and the $\ce{C-C-H}$ angle will decrease making **the substituents about the anionic carbon appear more puckered**.

Comment: I don't get the leap that s character will be removed from the bonds. I would assume the lone pair to be in a p like orbital, increasing s character in the bonds. Could you clarify that please.

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Just like in ammonia where the molecule is approximately tetrahedral 
 with the lone pair in an approximately $\ce{sp^3}$ orbital; this being a lower energy geometry than the molecule being planar with the lone pair in a p orbital.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I somehow got my reasoning the wrong way around.