# Why does B12H12 Borane not exist?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, bond, synthesis

Whenever I searched "$\ce{B12H12}$ Borane", I can't seem to find anything, and get met with only the dianion of $\ce{B12H12}$. Why doesn't $\ce{B12H12}$ exist on its own?

Comment: The general formulae of boranes are $\ce{B_nH_{n+4}}$ and $\ce{B_nH_{n+6}}$.

Comment: Apparently polymeric BH exists - perhaps  B12H12 could be an intermediate that further polymerises. It's just too unsaturated.

Comment: Hypercloso boranes are generally unstable. However, its derivates are known. For mre details see this: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-3773(20010504)40:9%3C1664::AID-ANIE16640%3E3.0.CO;2-O

Comment: Also see this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/39647/why-do-closo-boranes-have-a-2%e2%88%92-charge