# How can borane exist?

Tags: bond

*Disclaimer: Sorry if this is a noob question, I am a high school chem student.*

So I was reading my textbook in preparation for the midterm, and it talked about exceptions to the octet rule.

I understand that they exist, and what they are, but how are the chemicals structurally stable?

I also know that they are reactive, but that still doesn't help.

How do they exist?

I was thinking something like only under high pressure/heat, but I can't find anything to back that up.  Amazingly, google hasn't help.

Can somebody please explain?

Comment: Also, feel free to edit my tags.  I am new here.

Comment: Octet rule is less absolute than you seem to think. Sure, it would be nice to have a full octet, but what if the electrons are just not there? Then we'll have to do without, that's all.

Comment: Search for 'octet rule' [here](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=octet+rule). There are a whole bunch of questions which will answer yours.

Comment: related http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-makes-banana-bonds-possible-in-diborane

Comment: @IvanNeretin Okay.  I didn't know that, and assumed the atoms just wouldn't form a molecule in that case.