# How many electrons does boron have on average in B2H6?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

The boron interaction with hydrogen gives it one electron I suppose, but then the octet is not complete. So how many electrons does the boron atom have exactly and why?

Comment: Don't use mathjax in titles, also you used it improperly.

Comment: Six for each as you can count. See http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-makes-banana-bonds-possible-in-diborane