# Bond Angle in Diborane, B2H6

Tags: molecular-structure, vsepr-theory

Why are the bond angles in the diborane $\ce{B2H6}$ ring much less than $\ce{109.5^o}$? Below is the structure:

[image: Diborane]

[This](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/~cantrill/30A_F05/Diborane.pdf) source says that the boron atoms are approximately $\ce{sp^3}$ hybridized, so I thought that the bond angles of the ring would be approximately $\ce{109.5^o}$. However, the diagram indicates that the angles of the ring are $\ce{97^o}$ and $\ce{83^o}$. Why is this so?

Comment: It's a 4-membered ring...

Comment: Diborane is better **not** thought of in terms of hybridization and bond angles. Think of cyclobutane: no multiple bonds, hence $sp^3$, hence should be $109.5^\circ$, but no, it is more like $90^\circ$. How so?

Comment: So it has ~90 degree bonds to relieve some torsional strain?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-makes-banana-bonds-possible-in-diborane (full disclosure, it's my question).  @IvanNeretin hope you can forgive our hybridization slant to the question :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What makes banana bonds possible in diborane?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-makes-banana-bonds-possible-in-diborane)

Comment: It doesn’t seem to me that the proposed duplicate discusses bond angles.